# como crear una paginacion con material en ui React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Estoy tratando de usar el componente paginacion de material ui en React pero no entiendo muy bien la documentacion, no se como seleccionar los items o objetos que se van a paginar.

nisiquiera se como inicar lo unico que he intentado es esto pero se que no funciona asi.

PD: TarjetaServicios es un componente que renderiza una tarjeta. quiero mostrar 3 tarjetas y en la siguiente pagina otras 3 y asi.

```
 <Pagination count={10}>
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
       <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4}>
          <TarjetaServicios NombreEmpresa='Clases de manejo'></TarjetaServicios>
                        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4}>
          <TarjetaServicios NombreEmpresa='Clases de Ingles'></TarjetaServicios>
                        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4}>
          <TarjetaServicios NombreEmpresa='Servicio de limpieza'></TarjetaServicios>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    </Pagination>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. Español, Por favor compartenos el código de lo que has intentado, [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola, he añadido lo unico que he intentado.

Comment: puedes agregar el link de la documentación en la que estas basando por favor?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto un ejemplo básico ya que al parecer quieres colocar datos "quemados".

```
const pagination = {
    1: [
      {
        name: 'Clases de manejo',
      },
      {
        name: 'Clases de Inglés',
      },
      {
        name: 'Servicio de limpieza',
      },
    ],
    2: [
      {
        name: 'Pagina 2 - Nombre 1',
      },
      {
        name: 'Pagina 2 - Nombre 2',
      },
      {
        name: 'Pagina 2 - Nombre 3',
      },
    ],
  };

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    setPage(value);
  };
```

**JSX**:

```
<Grid container spacing={1}>
    {pagination[page].map((pag) => (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4}>
          <TarjetaServicios NombreEmpresa={pag.name} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
 </Grid>
 <Pagination count={2} page={page} onChange={handleChange} />
```

El **count** corresponde al número de páginas que quieres que tenga.

Para hacerlo más dinámico podrías hacer esto

```
const count = Object.keys(pagination).length
```

Y lo reemplazas

```
<Pagination count={count} page={page} onChange={handleChange} />
```

**Nota**: Cuando el componente no debería tener nada en medio (***children***), no es necesario que lo cierres con el mismo, basta con algo como:

```
<TarjetaServicios></TarjetaServicios> // NO
<TarjetaServicios /> // RECOMENDABLE
```

Comment: podrias explicarme como funciona? es que exactamente no se como es que funciona, lo quiero hacer con un array de objetos y no me da

Comment: tienes que tener separado ello por página o index, así como te mostré en el ejemplo del const pagination. La paginación simplemente se encarga de actualizar el número en el state y ese número es el que indica el index en el objeto de pagination. Separa tu array de objetos así como te mostré en el ejemplo y te debería de funcionar.